# Cordova / PhoneGap Plugin Permission Settings for NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-build, image-gallery

> App attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data

Answer (score 0):

> Cordova / PhoneGap Plugin Permission Settings for
>   NSCameraUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and
>   NSMicrophoneUsageDescription in iOS  by adding a declaration to the
>   Config.xml file

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="*">
  <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the camera." />
  <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the microphone." />
  <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="App would like to access the library." />
</plugin>
```